# elsarticle class not displaying email addresses

Tags: titles, elsarticle

I am trying to format an article using the elsarticle class.  I have followed the documentation included with the class file, but for some unknown (and incredibly irritating) reason the email addresses are not displayed in the frontmatter.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\title{Remarks on something interesting}

\author[myu]{Author 1}
\ead{a1@myuniversity.edu}

\author[myu]{Author 2 \corref{cor1}}
\ead{a2@myuniversity.edu}

\address[myu]{My Department, My Building, My University in My City}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to make the email addresses display?

Comment: @cyberSingularity: that worked beautifully.  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.  And thanks!

Comment: I forgot to say that you are welcome, and I thought it was a good question. ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Although I agree that it is not clear from the documentation or the [8th entry in the FAQ](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ_-_elsarticle.cls) pointed out by Werner, all the templates use `\title`, `\author`, `\ead` etc after `\begin{document}` and `\begin{frontmatter}`.

The reason it does not work before `\begin{document}` is that (for some reason), it writes the email addresses to the `aux` file (which means it needs two runs), and the `aux` file doesn't get read and re-opened for writing until `\begin{document}` (so in fact you see lines like `\emailauthor{a1@myuniversity.edu}{Author 1}` appearing on the terminal instead of getting written to the `aux` file).

Note that the `frontmatter` environment does nothing except `\maketitle` at the end (and some grouping), so I guess the supported syntax is to replace your `\maketitle` with the `frontmatter` environment. I have also done this in the following modification of your example.

I have also deleted the unwanted space between the author name and `\corref`.

Remember that you need to compile twice to see the e-mail addresses.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Remarks on something interesting}

\author[myu]{Author 1}
\ead{a1@myuniversity.edu}

\author[myu]{Author 2\corref{cor1}}
\ead{a2@myuniversity.edu}

\address[myu]{My Department, My Building, My University in My City}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Image of footer displaying the e-mail addresses (inspired by Gonzalo Medina's previous answer):

[image: Image of footer]

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering: the `abstract` and `keyword` environments should appear in the `frontmatter` environment too.