# Placing date on the front matter (elsarticle document class)

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter

Is there a neater way to place date on the front matter (elsarticle document class)?

```
\documentclass[final,authoryear,1p,times,letterpaper,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{thr}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{cor}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\crefname{ass}{Assumption}{Assumptions}
\crefname{df}{Definiton}{Definitons}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pifont}% for openstar in the title footnotes;
\usepackage{natbib}% for citation processing;
\usepackage{geometry}% for margin settings;
\usepackage{fleqn}% for left aligned equations;
\usepackage{graphicx}% for graphics inclusion;
\usepackage{txfonts}% optional font package, if the document is to be formatted with Times and compatible math fonts;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Random title\tnoteref{t1}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Very preliminary and incomplete. All errors remain our own.}
\author[jd]{John Doe}
\author[jnd]{Jane Doe}
\address[jd]{John Doe's University}
\address[jnd]{Jane Doe's University\vskip 18pt \textnormal{\today}}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\date{\today}` does not work?

Comment: I think `elsarticle` allows for `maketitle`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84573/elsarticle-class-not-displaying-email-addresses

Comment: @EthanBolker Just checked, `frontmatter` just calls `maketitle`.

Comment: Are you submitting to elsevier? They decide on what goes to the title.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: it doesn't.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'm not submitting; I just like the way things look using it.

Comment: If you are not submitting, i think you are fine doing it the way you are currently doing it. Well, a bit cleaner would be `\par\vspace{18pt}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit subjective, but a "neater" way is to patch the `\MaketitleBox` and `\pprintMaketitle` commands to automatically add the date halfway between the address and abstract (keeping the default 36pt vertical space). This way you are not passing the date to the `\address` command (which is a bit hackish).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%
```

In your MWE (removing the superfluous packages):

```
\documentclass[final,authoryear,1p,times,letterpaper,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Random title\tnoteref{t1}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Very preliminary and incomplete. All errors remain our own.}
\author[jd]{John Doe}
\author[jnd]{Jane Doe}
\address[jd]{John Doe's University}
\address[jnd]{Jane Doe's University}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]