# E-mail adresses (EAD comment)

Tags: texstudio

I want to write the author's e-mail addresses with ead command, but it gives @ sign in a bad way, how can I format the ead command and with adding hyperlink?

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What do you mean by the "ead command"? That's not something I recognise as standard LaTeX - where is it defined?  What do you mean by "gives the @ sign in a bad way" do you dislike the font?  If you can add a add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which we can compile to replicate your undesirable @ sign that may help identify your issues.

Comment: Related: [`elsarticle` class not displaying email addresses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84573/5764)

Comment: You need to place your `\maketitle`-related content *after* `\begin{document}`. A hyperlink `mailto:..@...` should automatically be added by the PDF viewer.

Comment: Thank you very much,  It is in elsearticle package, but when I use ead command to write e-mail addresses, I couldn't get the format that I want. And in addition I want to hyperlink.

Comment: @jansed Can you please add a http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228 ?

Comment: I couldn't do it, and I am not very good at Latex , unfortunately.

Comment: If someone can help me, It'd be okay. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elsarticle class not displaying email addresses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84573/elsarticle-class-not-displaying-email-addresses)