# about corresponding author

Tags: templates, elsarticle, journal-publishing, author

I have three questions, I wrote them on image as red color.

first : I want to change Author 3^(a^*) to Author 3^(a, *)

Second : How can I add email address of corresponding author?

(Third : Is it fine to leave line below of abstract? )

[image]

Code :

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{indentfirst}\setlength\parindent{2em} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\journal{Journal of CCCCCC}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different     styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{TITLETITLE}

\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}


\author{%
Author1\affmark[a], Author2\affmark[b], Author3\affmark[a*]\\
\affaddr{\affmark[a]Blah1}\\
\affaddr{\affmark[b]Blah2}\\
\address[mymainaddress]{Address1}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{Address2}
}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author to: Blahblah about     corres autho}




\begin{abstract}
Abstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1, keyword2

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers


\section*{References}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Usually one does ask **one** question in a post!

Comment: And furthermore note that you are using the `elsarticle` class which has its own (and pretty good) styles for authors and their affiliation so you don't need you `newcommand\affaddr{...}`. Furthermore I don't see a point in redefining anything, when it apparently is the way the Journal wants it to be.

Comment: For 2nd query, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84573/elsarticle-class-not-displaying-email-addresses

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot remove the line after the abstract. I can obtained the behaviour you ask for but it is not standard.

```
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
Author3\affmark[a,$_{\null\textsuperscript{*}}$]\\
```

[image: a,*]

However, since this is for a journal, the editor will finally remove all your modifications to fulfil the journal requirements. In my opinion, don't waste time trying to modify editor templates.

Here you have the full code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{indentfirst}\setlength\parindent{2em} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\journal{Journal of CCCCCC}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different     styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{TITLETITLE}

\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}


\author{%
    Author1\affmark[a], Author2\affmark[b],
    Author3\affmark[a,$_{\null\textsuperscript{*}}$]\\
\affaddr{\affmark[a]Blah1}\\
\affaddr{\affmark[b]Blah2}\\
\address[mymainaddress]{Address1}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{Address2}
}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{corresponding@author.com}




\begin{abstract}
Abstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah     blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah blahAbstract blah 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1, keyword2

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers


\section*{References}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for "don't waste time trying to modify editor templates."